# I have a problem with the 9 buttons for my slide puzzle

Tags: c#

I am currently having trouble with my slide puzzle. The thing is that the codes work but only for the 9 buttons that appeared out of no where. Here is an image of it.

[image]

This is the code I used to run the program.

```
public partial class frmSlide : Form
{
    /*
     * frmSlide -constructor
     * 
     */
    DateTime TimedSolved = DateTime.Now;
    bool starting = false;
    bool changed = false;
    const int rows = 3;
    const int cols = 3;
    Button blkButton= new Button();
    public Button[,] btnArray = new Button[rows, cols];

    Button[,] buttons = new Button[3, 3];
     
    public frmSlide()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
    }
    

    /*
     *  allNumberButton_Click - click event handler for allNumberButton
     *  
     *  Parameter: sender -who sent the event
     *  Parameter: e -info about the event
     *  Return: nothing
     */
    private void frmSlide_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
            blkButton.Text = " ";
            int curNum = 1;
            for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
                {
                    Button b;
                    b = new Button();
                    b.Location = new Point(100 + (y * 50), 100 + (x * 50));
                    b.Height = 40;
                    b.Width = 40;
                    b.Text = curNum.ToString();
                    btnArray[x, y] = b;
                    b.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    b.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, (float)15.0);
                    b.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.allNumberButton_Click);
                    this.Controls.Add(b);
                    curNum++;
                }
            }
            btnArray[rows - 1, cols - 1].Text = "";
            blkButton = btnArray[rows - 1, cols - 1];
            blkButton.Text = " ";
        
    }


  

    private void allNumberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        {
            Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
            if (clickedButton.Text == "")
            {
                goto done;
            }

            Point clicked = clickedButton.Location;
            int clickedX = clicked.X;
            int clickedY = clicked.Y;
            Point blank = blkButton.Location;
            int blankX = blank.X;
            int blankY = blank.Y;
            int distanceX = Math.Abs(clickedX - blankX);
            int distanceY = Math.Abs(clickedY - blankY);
            changed = false;
            if ((distanceX == 50 && distanceY == 0) ||
                    (distanceX == 0 && distanceY == 50))
            {
                changed = true;
                string tmp = clickedButton.Text;
                clickedButton.Text = "";
                blkButton.Text = tmp;
                blkButton = clickedButton;
            }

            if (changed == true)
            {
                if (btnArray[rows - 1, cols - 1].Text != "")
                {
                    goto done;
                }
                int checkNum = 1;
                for (int a = 0; a < rows; a++)
                {
                    for (int b = 0; b < cols; b++)
                    {
                        if (a == rows - 1 && b == cols - 1)
                        {
                            goto done2;
                        }
                        if (btnArray[a, b].Text != checkNum.ToString())
                        {
                            goto done;
                        }
                        checkNum++;
                    }
                }
            done2:;
                if (starting == false)
                {
                    DateTime nowSolved = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan lengthOfTime = nowSolved - TimedSolved;
                    double hours = lengthOfTime.TotalHours;
                    int hours2 = Convert.ToInt32(hours);
                    double minutes = lengthOfTime.TotalMinutes;
                    int minutes2 = Convert.ToInt32(minutes);
                    double seconds = lengthOfTime.TotalSeconds;
                    int seconds2 = Convert.ToInt32(seconds);
                    MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! \n \n It took you " + hours2 +
                        " hours " + minutes2 + " minutes " + seconds2 + " seconds \n \n"
                        + " to solve it!");
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        done:;

        }
    }

    /*
     *  btnReset_Click - click event handler 
     *  .text
     *  Parameter: sender -who sent the event
     *  Parameter: e -info about the event
     *  Return: nothing
     */
    
        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            int reset = 1;
            for (int c = 0; c < rows; c++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < cols; l++)
                {
                    btnArray[c, l].Text = reset.ToString();
                    reset++;
                    btnArray[rows - 1, cols - 1].Text = "";
                    blkButton = btnArray[rows - 1, cols - 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }

   
   

    /*
     *  btnExit_Click -click event handler 
     *  
     *  Parameter: sender -who sent the event
     *  Parameter: e -info about the event
     *  Return: nothing
     */
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    /*
     *  frmSlide_Load- Load event handler 
     *  
     *  Parameter: sender -who sent the event
     *  Parameter: e -info about the event
     *  Return: nothing
     */
    
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            starting = true;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++)
            {
                int rndNumberX = rnd.Next(3);
                int rndNumberY = rnd.Next(3);
                Button random = btnArray[rndNumberX, rndNumberY];
                random.PerformClick();
            }

            starting = false;

        }

    
}
```

Can you help me fix this problem with a solution because it is hard for me to figure out what happened?
I thought it might be the code I entered in the form load.

Comment: Have you debugged this?

Comment: are you talking about in visual studio or stack overflow?

Comment: Your code is ADDING the buttons to the form. Are you sure there are not "existing" buttons already on the form?

Comment: I am talking about visual studio, stackoverflow is not a debugging service unfortunately

Comment: The existing buttons is the one at the top. What i'm trying to do is remove the extra buttons in place the codes in the existing ones for my slide puzzle to work. Do you have an idea what I should do

Comment: Remove the exiting buttons from the form.

Comment: The existing button was made by me, do you know how I would fix it to make my 9 buttons work? or how should I code the 9 buttons?

Comment: From my test using your code. Remove the existing "numbered" 9 buttons that exist on the form. The only buttons on the form would be the start, reset and exit buttons. Your code is adding the 9 numbered buttons.

Comment: I know what you mean but she wants us to use the existing numbers because it is part of our assignment just to have those working. Do you know how to get the existing buttons to work instead/

Comment: _"she wants us to use the existing numbers"_ ... Then "why" is your code adding the buttons? From what you said... remove/comment out the "code" that adds the buttons to the form. Then, with each existing button on the form, set each buttons "click" event to the `allNumberButton_Click` event.

Comment: I was attempting to say that in your previous question @BurshellAgness.  I tested your code and it functions well.  So what you're talking about then and now are buttons that are added from designer, vs buttons added programmatically.

Comment: programmatically I am having trouble with the buttons. Just needed to know how I would remove all extra buttons and code in the existing 9 buttons to make it work. Did anyone of you seen the image?

Comment: I set all the buttons on the allnumberbuttons_click event handler. and still the same results.

Comment: I'll provide an answer here for you to review on shortly.. but I don't know the name of your buttons, and the `allnumberbuttons_click` is deriving\calculating the distance between buttons to apply functionality.. it will have to be updated to the correct values

Comment: how do I get the correct values?

Comment: Did you remove/comment out the code that ADDS the buttons? In the current code, you have a line… `public Button[,] btnArray = new Button[rows, cols];` … this is an empty 3x3 array of `Button`s. Since your current code is ADDING the buttons from your “code” into that array … `btnArray[x, y] = b;` , then you will need to change this to add the “existing” buttons that are already on the form to this array. Otherwise, when the code in the `allNumberButton_Click` executes and tries to use the array… `btnArray[a, b]`…, it will have the buttons from the form.

Comment: btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btnBlank is the 9 buttons

Comment: Add those buttons to the button array... `btnArray[0,0] = btn1`, `btnArray[0,1] = btn2`... etc.

Comment: @JohnG how do I change it, to add the "existing" buttons?

Comment: Look at Brett's answer.

Comment: JohnG you want me to add all btnArray to each 9 buttons for that line?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove the generation of those buttons in your `frmSlide_Load` event handler.

You'll also need to assign your existing buttons to `btnArray`.

I'll demonstrate how to do that using object initializer.

- Comment out all lines in `frmSlide_Load`
- Add `InitializeSliderButtons` method
- Add `InitializeSliderButtons()` line in `frmSlide`
- Handle `distanceX == 50 && distanceY == 0` related checks\logic in `allNumberButton_Click`. The are probably not correct values as those existing buttons look different in width\height\spacing.

```
public frmSlide()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeSliderButtons();
}

public void InitializeSliderButtons()
{
    btnArray = new Button[,]
    {
        {
            btn1,
            btn2,
            btn3
        },
        {
            btn4,
            btn5,
            btn6
        },
        {
            btn7,
            btn8,
            btnBlank
        }
    };

    foreach (var button in btnArray)
    {
        button.Click += new EventHandler(this.allNumberButton_Click);
    }

    blkButton = btnArray[rows - 1, cols - 1];
    blkButton.Text = " ";
}

private void frmSlide_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//    blkButton.Text = " ";
//    int curNum = 1;
//    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
//    {
//        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
//        {
//            Button b;
//            b = new Button();
//            b.Location = new Point(100 + (y * 50), 100 + (x * 50));
//            b.Height = 40;
//            b.Width = 40;
//            b.Text = curNum.ToString();
//            btnArray[x, y] = b;
//            b.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
//            b.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, (float)15.0);
//            b.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.allNumberButton_Click);
//            this.Controls.Add(b);
//            curNum++;
//        }
//    }
//    btnArray[rows - 1, cols - 1].Text = "";
//    blkButton = btnArray[rows - 1, cols - 1];
//    blkButton.Text = " ";
}
```

---

To determine your form button values, you'll look at the `Location` property of the `Button` on the designer (in the ***Properties*** window\view)

[image: Sample of Form Button Location]

In the above screenshot, it's **170, 122** (X, Y). The button to the right of it would have to be **220, 122** (X+50, Y+0) for your current logic\check to work.  You'll reflect on those locations and differences and update your logic\checks to whatever you determine it should be.

Comment: Brett Caswell where do I update the logics\checks

Comment: the X, Y that is

Comment: in `allNumberButton_Click`, look for the line `distanceX == 50 && distanceY == 0`

Comment: If I were to  do it would it b distanceX == 46 && distance Y == 0. This is because I have btn 1 = 32, 24 and btn 2 = 78, 24. How would I display that?

Comment: Also how do I set the btn array on the 9 buttons. will it all be a list of 9 functions

Comment: "how do I set the btn array on the 9 buttons" please read my answer, as I have already provided instruction on that.. in regards to `46`, that seems right.. so `distanceX == 46 && distanceY == 0 || distanceX == 0 && distanceY == 46`

Comment: I set the btn array like you posted and it doesn't do anything. You know why?

Answer (score 1):

I must say you need to take break and sit back. You are making this FAR more complicated than it has to be. Remember… KISS (Keep It Super Simple).

From what you stated, you are given a form with nine (9) `Button` objects on the form (btn1, btn2…btn9). The buttons are displayed in a 3x3 array or 3 rows of 3 columns. Given this, it is not a bad idea as you started to make a 3x3 `Button` array to “hold” the buttons.

One thing that you need to “forget about” at this time is the “blank” button. To start, let’s just say it is another button, it is irrelevant at this point if it is “blank” or not. So, let us fill the 3x3 `Button` array using the “existing” `Buttons` on the form. In addition, since we want ALL the button’s `Click` event to fire the same event, we can go ahead and wire them up also. Something like…

```
public void InitializeSliderButtons() {
  btnArray[0, 0] = btn1;
  btnArray[0, 1] = btn2;
  btnArray[0, 2] = btn3;
  btnArray[1, 0] = btn4;
  btnArray[1, 1] = btn5;
  btnArray[1, 2] = btn6;
  btnArray[2, 0] = btn7;
  btnArray[2, 1] = btn8;
  btnArray[2, 2] = btn9;
  foreach (var button in btnArray) {
    button.Click += new EventHandler(allNumberButton_Click);
  }
}
```

Now we have the `Buttons` in a nice and neat 3x3 array. Next, we need to move to the buttons “Click” event `allNumberButton_Click`. When this event is fired, the first problem we have is figuring out “which” button was clicked. This is easily done, however, there is one button that we want to “ignore” if it is clicked and it doesn’t matter “which” button it is. That button would be the `Button` that has the text set to a blank string. In other words, if the blank button is clicked then we do not have to do anything. So, the first check in this event is to check for this blank button.

```
private void allNumberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
  if (clickedButton.Text == "")
    return;
  // if code execution gets here then the clicked button is NOT the blank button
}
```

After this if the code did not return, then we DO need to find out “which” Button was clicked. In this case the only way we can tell which button is clicked is by looking at the button name. We already know the button names are `btn1`, `btn2`… etc. However, EVEN if we know the button name, then we would still have to figure out “where” that button was in relation to the 3x3 button array. It is irrelevant what the button name is, we need the position in the button array. In other words, I only care about “which” button was clicked in relation to the 3x3 button array.

If we can get the clicked button's X,Y position in the `btnArray`, then it will make it trivial to check the buttons above, below, left and right of this button. If any of the above, below, left or right buttons are empty/blank, then we can switch the two button’s text value.

Given this, I will use a `Point` object as it has an X and Y property we can use. To help we will create a very simple method that takes a `Button`, and returns a `Point.` We will know the “position” of the button by its name. So `btn1` would return `Point(0,0)`, `btn2` would return `Pont(0,1)`… etc. This will help in the click event by giving us the X and Y coordinates of the clicked button in relation to the 3x3 button array. If we are given a button that does not match any of the name’s we are looking for then we will return a -1, -1. This method may look something like…

```
private Point GetButtonPosition(Button button) {
  if (button.Name == "btn1")
    return new Point(0, 0);
  if (button.Name == "btn2")
    return new Point(0, 1);
  if (button.Name == "btn3")
    return new Point(0, 2);
  if (button.Name == "btn4")
    return new Point(1, 0);
  if (button.Name == "btn5")
    return new Point(1, 1);
  if (button.Name == "btn6")
    return new Point(1, 2);
  if (button.Name == "btn7")
    return new Point(2, 0);
  if (button.Name == "btn8")
    return new Point(2, 1);
  if (button.Name == "btn9")
    return new Point(2, 2);
  return new Point(-1, -1);
}
```

This will update the click method like below…

```
private void allNumberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
  if (clickedButton.Text == "")
    return;
  Point buttonPosition = GetButtonPosition(clickedButton);
}
```

Now that we have the clicked buttons position in relation to the 3x3 all we need to do is check to see if one of the buttons above, below, left or right of this button is an “empty/blank” button. In this example, I have created another method that takes a Button and returns a Point object.

In this method, we will check buttons above, below, left and right of the given button and see if any of those buttons are the empty/blank button. If we find one of the buttons IS the empty/blank button, then, we will return the X, Y position in relation to the 3x3 array of that blank button. If none of the buttons above, below, left and right are the blank button, then we will return a -1, -1 to indicate that none of the button are the blank button. This method may look something like…

```
private Point GetBlankButtonNextToGivenButtonPosition(Point btnPosition) {
  // check buttons to the left and right of the given button
  if (btnPosition.X - 1 >= 0) {
    if (btnArray[btnPosition.X - 1, btnPosition.Y].Text == "") {
      return new Point(btnPosition.X - 1, btnPosition.Y);
    }
  }
  if (btnPosition.X + 1 < 3) {
    if (btnArray[btnPosition.X + 1, btnPosition.Y].Text == "") {
      return new Point(btnPosition.X + 1, btnPosition.Y);
    }
  }
  // Check for buttons above and below the given button
  if (btnPosition.Y - 1 >= 0) {
    if (btnArray[btnPosition.X, btnPosition.Y - 1].Text == "") {
      return new Point(btnPosition.X, btnPosition.Y - 1);
    }
  }
  if (btnPosition.Y + 1 < 3) {
    if (btnArray[btnPosition.X, btnPosition.Y + 1].Text == "") {
      return new Point(btnPosition.X, btnPosition.Y + 1);
    }
  }
  // blank not found
  return new Point(-1, -1);
}
```

With this, now we can check and see if any of the buttons above, below, right or left of the clicked button is the blank button. When we call the method above, IF we get a Point with values of -1, -1, then we know that we do NOT need to swap the button text values. On the other hand, if we get any other number then that would indicate that there IS a blank button next to the clicked button. With this we would have all the info we need to swap the text values. We have the position of the clicked button, and we also have the position of the blank button “next” to the clicked button. This should complete the Click event code…

```
private void allNumberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
  if (clickedButton.Text == "")
    return;
  Point buttonPosition = GetButtonPosition(clickedButton);
  if (buttonPosition.X != -1) {
    Point blankPosition = GetBlankButtonNextToGivenButtonPosition(buttonPosition);
    if (blankPosition.X != -1) {
      btnArray[blankPosition.X, blankPosition.Y].Text = clickedButton.Text;
      clickedButton.Text = "";
    }
  }
  if (BoardIsCorrect()) {
    MessageBox.Show("You solved the puzzle!");
  }
}
```

I have another method called `BoardIsCorrect` to check and see if the numbers are in the correct sequence and if so, return true. This and the start and reset methods are also added below.

```
public Button[,] btnArray = new Button[3, 3];
Random rand = new Random();

private void frmSlide_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  InitializeSliderButtons();
}

private bool BoardIsCorrect() {
  if (btnArray[0, 0].Text == "1" &&
      btnArray[0, 1].Text == "2" &&
      btnArray[0, 2].Text == "3" &&
      btnArray[1, 0].Text == "4" &&
      btnArray[1, 1].Text == "5" &&
      btnArray[1, 2].Text == "6" &&
      btnArray[2, 0].Text == "7" &&
      btnArray[2, 1].Text == "8"
    ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
  int nextRand;
  int randIndex;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      randIndex = rand.Next(0, numbers.Count);
      nextRand = numbers[randIndex];
      if (nextRand != 9) {
        btnArray[i, j].Text = nextRand.ToString();
      }
      else {
        btnArray[i, j].Text = "";
      }
      numbers.RemoveAt(randIndex);
    }
  }
}

private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int rows = 3;
  int cols = 3;
  int count = 1;
  for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      btnArray[r, c].Text = count++.ToString();
    }
  }
  btnArray[2, 2].Text = "";
}
```

I hope this make sense.

Comment: Thanks bro, I appreciate your help. JohnG.